# How to solve $y(1+y'^2)=C$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The power of $y'$ was missed by accident. I apologize for this mistake!**

$$
y(1+(y')^2)=C
$$
where $y(x)$ is an ordinary function and $C$ is a constant.

If any similar questions are asked before, please remind me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try isolating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and then separating variables.

Comment: @Tavish Could you elaborate on the method? I don't think I catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that  $y(1 + y'^2) = C$ can be written as $y' = \sqrt{\frac{C}{y} -1}$.

So we have $$ \frac{\sqrt ydy}{\sqrt{C-y}} = dx$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.